# Sending JSON via Postman causes an error in my Node.js service

Tags: arrays, node.js, schema, postman

I created schema in node.js. It worked before I included arrays.

This is my schema code:

```
const Item = new item_Schema({
    info:{
        title:{type:String, required:true},
        bad_point:{type:Number, 'default':0},
        Tag:{type:String, required:true}
    },
    review:{
        Review_text:{type:Array, required:true},
        Phone_list:{type:Array, required:true},
        LatLng_list:{type:Array, required:true}
    }
});

Item.statics.create = function(info, review){
    const list = new this({
        info:{
            title,
            bad_point,
            Tag
        },
        review:{
            Review_text,
            Phone_list,
            LatLng_list
        }
    });

    return list.save();
};
```

This is my `register` code:

```
exports.register = (req, res) => {
    const { info, review } = req.body

    const create = (list) => {
        return Item.create(info, review)
    }

    const respond = () => {
        res.json({
            message: 'place route registered successfully'
        })
    }

    const onError = (error) => {
        res.status(409).json({
            message: error.message
        })
    }


    RouteReviewItem.findOneBytitle(title)
    .then(create)
    .then(respond)
    .catch(onError)
}
```

And this is the Postman JSON raw code:

```
{
    "info":"{
        "title":"test title",
        "badPoint":"0"
        "Tag":"tag1"
        }",
    "review":"{
        "Review_text":["1번리뷰", "2번리뷰", "3번리뷰"],
        "Phone_list":"["010-0000-0000", "010-1111-1111", "010-2222-2222"],
        "LatLng_list":["111.1111,111.1111", "222.222,222.222","333.3333,333.3333"]
        }"
}
```

This is the error I get in Postman:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 17
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (C:\MainServer\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    at C:\MainServer\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\MainServer\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\MainServer\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\MainServer\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1045:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Is this a problem with postman? Or the node.js side?
I looked at the node.js book I was studying, but could not find any relevant information.

Comment: You've got an extra speech mark.  See `"regi_info":"{`, there's a " right before the {.  By specifying a quote mark, the value of regi info will be that string, but what you want is an object, so lose the quotes.  p.s.  Well asked question ^^

Comment: @Dan Rayson Thank you very much! 
I've fixed the issue Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine, you have an issue with JSON you used for testing. For further testing and debugging, I suggest that you verify that the requests you send you the endpoint are correct by using a service like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) (or any offlne tool that does the same). For the request you posted in the question, this service complains:

```
Error: Parse error on line 2:
{   "info": "{  "title": "test t
----------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Next time, before sending a request, make sure it is correct syntactically. That way you'll know that there is a problem with your code, and won't spend time debugging a non-existent issue.

Comment: Definitely I needed to inform the error.
I can save my time by referring to what you suggestion. Thank you for your recommendation.